# How do I print a whole function output to a file in C

Tags: c, file, printf

I have a program composed of multiple functions and each function has multipl printf statements, and I need each of those statements printed to a file. 
Right now, I'm just duplicating each printf and making it an fprintf statement, however this is highly inefficient. 
 Could I perhaps just fprintf an entire function, even if it doesn't return anything?

I've searched the site but the only answer I found was to use system calls and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: To print all the program's output to a file start the program with output redirection like this: `myprogram 1>myprogram-output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can create another function that takes a value to print. This function will print the value and also store it in the file.

Now everywhere in your code where you want to print, just call the above function and your problem is solved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear to me what the problem is you're trying to accomplish but it sounds like you're trying to send all of your program's output to a file. The easiest way to do that is simply to redirect `stdout` to a new file when you run the program. For example, if you're running in Linux, type the following in the command line: `./myprogram > output.txt`

That will execute the program `myprogram` and send the output to a new file called `output.txt`.